# Add to cart mini icon on mobile not showing no. of products added on it

Tags: magento-1.9

Earlier when we use to add products to cart, it use to redirect us to the checkout page, which we didn't wanted. So after the new settings now when we add products to cart it does to the mini cart on the top right side and there you can see the value on the mini cart like 1,2,3 (no of products added to card). This works smoothly on the desktop, but on the mobile the mini cart doesn't show any products no on the cart even after adding products to cart.

For more detail, i also checked using path finder. On desktop when i do this process the mini cart count comes from summary.phtml & on the mobile when i do the process the mini card is showing there is from header.phtml no summary.phtml linked to it. So how do i link it ?

How can i solve this, Please help me out thanks.

Here the screenshot for the mobile version, the cart icon is not showing any no. even after adding few products to cart.

[image]

Comment: Can you also add screenshot.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: Earlier when we use to add products to cart, it use to redirect us to the checkout page, which we didn't wanted. So after the new settings now when we add products to cart it does to the mini cart on the top right side and there you can see the value on the mini cart like 1,2,3 (no of products added to card). This works smoothly on the desktop, but on the mobile the mini cart doesn't show any products no on the cart even after adding products to cart.

Comment: For more detail, i also checked using path finder. On desktop when i do this process the mini cart count comes from summary.phtml & on the mobile when i do the process the mini card is showing there is from header.phtml no summary.phtml linked to it. So how do i link it ?